# Breakdown point of weighted median

Tags: median, robust

I posted the same question on math.stackexchange, but haven't got any reply. So I will try my luck here:

In the context of robust statistics, there is the concept of breakdown point, which basically measures the proportion of outliers an estimator can handle before giving an arbitrary result: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics#Breakdown_point

For example, arithmetic mean has breakdown point $0$, while median has it as $0.5$, the highest possible.

My question is that how should we estimate the breakdown point for **weighted median**, which is the data point with the smallest $m$ that satisfies the following, when the set of $n$ data points are sorted in ascending order:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} \Omega_{i} \ge \sum_{j=m+1}^{n}\Omega_{j}$$

where $\Omega_{i}$ is the weight for point $i$.

More specifically, what relationship can we derive between the weights and breakdown point?

Comment: so the $\Omega_i$'s are the weights? Something seems to be missing...i can make its bdp go to 0 by giving weight 0 to all except one outlier

Comment: I think I see the answer lurking right there in your formula :-).  What happens to the weighted median when you greatly modify the first $m$ values?  The last $n-m$ values?

Comment: @user603, the weights are fixed beforehand, just the way they would be with most weighted data (e.g., frequency-weighted or probability-weighted datasets): you don't get to modify them.

Comment: @whuber: but the bdp is computed under worst possible weighting scheme...

Comment: @whuber:> in other words: just as the regular median will go the way of the majority of the observations, the weighted median will go the way of the observations with the majority of the weights....what makes it impossible  for a few outliers to have a lot of weight? That's what i meant when i wrote 'something is missing'

Comment: I beg to differ.  One fixes the weights in advance: this determines the problem.  (Usually, all weights are equal; this question contemplates unequal weights.)  The *most* weight a few outliers can possibly have is the sum of the largest weights: now go read my hint :-).

Comment: @whuber, I don't quite follow "the most weight a few outliers can possibly have is the sum of the largest weights". What do you mean by "the largest weights"? For your hint in the earlier comment, if all $n$ weights are fixed, then yes, the bdp would be $m/n$. However, what if we consider the following situation: the first $n$ weights are fixed, but a set of outliers come in with their respective weight, how many of them do we need to break down the weight median? That's what I meant by the relationship between the weights and the breakdown point.

Comment: I think then you will need to clarify what you mean by "weights" and how they are associated with "outliers," Aaron.  If the "first $n$ weights are fixed," then just what are the *other* weights implied by this statement?  How are you applying more than $n$ weights to just $n$ data values?  What does it mean for outliers to "come in" when you have stipulated that there are $n$ data points?